# OR statement in select part of query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I  have a query

```
SELECT 
        cd.signoffdate,
        min(cmp.dsignoff) as dsignoff
      FROM clients AS c 
      LEFT JOIN campaigns AS cmp ORDER BY dsignoff;
```

If I want to have something like this built into the postgres query will it work and how do I do it

if the `cd.signoffdate` is empty it should take `min(cmp.dsignoff) as dsignoff` as the value and then order by this column, so in other words it should order by `dsignoff` and `cd.signoffdate` and tread it as one column, is this possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could look like this:

```
SELECT c.client_id, COALESCE(c.signoffdate, min(cmp.dsignoff)) AS signoff
FROM   clients c 
LEFT   JOIN campaigns cmp ON cmp.client_id = c.client_id  -- join condition!
GROUP  BY c.client_id, cd.signoffdate                     -- group by!
ORDER  BY COALESCE(c.signoffdate, min(cmp.dsignoff));
```

Or, with simplified syntax:

```
SELECT c.client_id, COALESCE(c.signoffdate, min(cmp.dsignoff)) AS signoff
FROM   clients c 
LEFT   JOIN campaigns cmp USING (client_id)
GROUP  BY 1, cd.signoffdate
ORDER  BY 2;
```

#### Major points:

- Used alias `c`, but referenced as `cd`.
- No join condition leads to cross join, probably not intended.
- Missing `GROUP BY`.
- I assume that you want to group by the primary key column of `clients` and call it `client_id`.
- I also assume that `client_id` links the two tables together.
- `COALESCE()` serves as fallback in case `signoffdate` IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ORDER BY coalesce(cd.signoffdate, min(cmp.dsignoff));
```

But don't you need some GROUP BY in your original query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(cd.signoffdate, min(cmp.dsignoff)) as dsignoff
```

I'm not sure if you can order by coalesce in Postgres - might be worth just ordering by both columns